# Pandas converting date time in string to datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in Pandas dataframe which is a datetime entry column in string.
I have tried using the the syntax but it gives rise to this error.

```
Syntax

pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], format = '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

```
Error
time data '2020-11-01 16:23:12' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: try it with capital Y (or don't put in format at all)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you've used the wrong format for the year.

```
pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try %Y,

this is the cheatsheet: https://strftime.org/